# Is it possible to use AND with three tables and using left join/inner join

Tags: sql

I am in need  of a very strange problem. I hope you brilliant guys will enjoy this problem (or may be it's an easy task for you :) ).

Here is the query I am using to return values from three tables

```
   select  listing.*
   , sum(review.rNumber) as nor
   , count(review.rNumber) as total
   , users.username from listing  
   where
   left join review on listing.lid=review.lID
   inner join users on users.uid=listing.cuid
   group by listing.lid
```

Now in this query I want to use an additional filter. It is returning all the values from `listing table` but I want to return all values using `WHERE cat='Hair' or something`

I don't have any idea how to insert where clues in this query.. Please let me know if it doable.
Thanks

Comment: put your where before your group by line

Comment: you need to put your conditions by your where too

Comment: like this "where cat='Hair' group by listing.lid" ??

Comment: yea, take a look at Jeremy Gurr's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the filter to apply before the group by:

```
select listing.*, sum(review.rNumber) as nor, count(review.rNumber) as total, users.username from listing 
left join review on listing.lid=review.lID
inner join users on users.uid=listing.cuid
where cat='Hair'
group by listing.lid
```

If you want it after, you use "having" instead:

```
select listing.*, sum(review.rNumber) as nor, count(review.rNumber) as total, users.username from listing 
left join review on listing.lid=review.lID
inner join users on users.uid=listing.cuid
group by listing.lid
having cat='Hair'
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join review on listing.lid=review.lID inner join users on users.uid=listing.cuid' at line 2

Comment: Oops, I copied the mistake that was already in the given query. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused, I tried this way before but never worked and now your one is working  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be as follow.

```
 select  listing.lid
   , sum(review.rNumber) as nor
   , count(review.rNumber) as total
   , users.username from listing  
   left join review on listing.lid=review.lID
   inner join users on users.uid=listing.cuid
   where 
   cat='Hair
   group by listing.lid,users.username
```

First of all, you need to follow

- Select
- From
- Where
- Group By

Second, if you use group by, you may not select any column that is not in aggregate function or in group by. Therefore, listing.* can not be done. If you need that values, put them in the both group by and select.

Comment: perfect, a bit confusion, how can I return all values from listing? It is returning lid.. But  I didn't get your "If you need that values, put them in the both group by and select.", could you please help?